# Printing value after "=" in linux

Tags: linux

I have a requirement from the below line

> /opt/update/data/abc.prop=15698

I need to display the output as below:

> 15698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract everything after the equals sign:

```
echo /opt/update/data/abc.prop=15698 | sed s/.*=//
```

The sed command matches all characters up to and including the equals sign and replaces it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer after trying the below. If any simpler one, please suggest

```
cat s1.txt|grep -o "=.*"|sort -u|grep -Po '\K[^=]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

echo /opt/update/data/abc.prop=15698 | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'

awk can be used as a field separator and output will be in the second field.